# How to print out the Chinese Character in PHP When an API is called?

Tags: php, api, character, vimeo, cjk

When my API is called, it shall return the video's title, description, pictures, and so on. And sometimes my video has Chinese characters. So when I printed out the JSON array, the Chinese character is showing something like this: **"\u4e00\u5bb6\u4e0a\u5e02\u4e0d\u4e45\u7684\u5bb6\u5177\u4e1a".**

So my question is, how can i print out the Chinese word when I called the API and print out?

```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  require ("vendor/autoload.php");
  use Vimeo\Vimeo;
   $client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

   $video_id ="xxxxx";
   $response = $client->request("/videos/$video_id");
   //var_dump($response['body']);

   if($response['status'] === 200){
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($response['body']);
   }
  else {
      echo json_encode($response['body']['error']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode` with some parameters to prevent the transformation of the chinese caracteres.

```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  require ("vendor/autoload.php");
  use Vimeo\Vimeo;
   $client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

   $video_id ="xxxxx";
   $response = $client->request("/videos/$video_id");
   //var_dump($response['body']);

   if($response['status'] === 200){
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     echo json_encode($response['body'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
   }
  else {
      echo json_encode($response['body']['error']);
  }
```

Comment: this is so helpful !! Coz i read thorugh many different answer and still it's not working. Stack overflow really needs more people like you who can understand the programmer's problem well.

Comment: Thanks bro. i'm really enjoying contributing with stack overflow.